# Remove values from an array in-place without using extra memory

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-arrays

I want to remove value `x` from an array and I have the following constraints:

1. I can only traverse the array once
2. No extra memory/data structures are allowed

so that

```
a = [1, 2, 'x', 3, 4, 5]
```

becomes

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None]
```

The case with only one `x` is trivial, I just shift everything one position left:

```
def removeSingleElement(value, array):
    i = 0
    while i < len(array)-1:
        if array[i] == value:
            for val in array[i:-1]:
                array[i] = array[i+1]
                i += 1 
        else:
            i += 1

    array[-1] = None
    return array
```

but how do I cope with an array with **repeated values**?

`a = [1, 'x', 2, 3, 'x', 4]`

should become

`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, None, None]`

(the idea is that I can't resize the array so I want to shift everything on the left and fill the rest with `Null`s values).

**Disclaimer**: this is not a Python question, I'm looking for the general algorithm and it just happens that I find Python convenient to express the idea ;)

Comment: Lol @Daniel I wish I were still in school :) No this came up during an interview and I'm trying to figure out what the trick was.

Comment: not getting.. means input is [1,2,3,'x',4,5] and output will be [1,2,3,4,5, None]  .. more input is [1,2,3,'x',4,5 'x'] and output will be [1,2,3,4,5]  after remove `x` value from the input list.

Comment: You don't need to shift the elements before the frst `x`. You need to shift elements between the first `x` and the second `x` one place to the left. You need to shift elements between the second `x` and the third `x` two places to the left. You need to shift elements between the third `x` and the fourth `x` three places to the left. You...

Comment: @n.m. : ha! thanks, that is what I was looking for. So simple once you know the solution :)

Comment: "No extra memory/data structures are allowed" should be "only a constant amount of extra memory is allowed" for the task to make any sense

Comment: @NiklasB. strictly speaking you're obviously right, but in the context of algorithm design "no extra memory" is usually a shortcut for "you can't allocate a new array or use any additional data structure"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are allowed to know the length of the array in advance and store a counter the following works:

```
def remove_element(value,array):
    shift = 0
    for index in xrange(len(array)):
        try:
            array[index] = array[index + shift]
            while array[index] == value:
                shift += 1
                array[index] = array[index + shift]
        except IndexError:
            array[index] = None
```

Comment: Nice catch the repeated values bug. I like this solution, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need two indices, one for reading and of writing:

```
def remove_element(value, array):
    reading_idx = writing_idx = 0
    while reading_idx < len(array):
        if array[reading_idx] != value:
            array[writing_idx] = array[reading_idx]
            writing_idx += 1
        reading_idx += 1
    while writing_idx < len(array):
        array[writing_idx] = None
        writing_idx += 1
```

Comment: You are iterating the list twice (at least partially).

Comment: What does the second `while` loop do? It iterates through the list, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye: he's not exactly iterating twice, he is traversing the array once with two pointers. The second `while` loop just sets the leftovers (if any) to `None`.

Comment: @laurids It means that iterating the list twice.

Comment: @thefourtheye I see what you mean but I don't think there's a way to do it otherwise (without using try/except as in the accepted answer). It is still pretty neat code, I'm grateful to Daniel for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be cheating, but...

```
def remove(value, array):
    try:
        while True:
            del(array[array.index(value)])
            array.append(None)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return array
```

Comment: this will work for `['x', 'x', 1, 2, 'x', 'x']` input ?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't, but updated one does. Though it doesn't answer the question as OP is looking for generic algorithm

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
def removeSingleElement(value, array):
    """
    Remove value from the input array.
    Input parameters:
        value: Remove Value.
        array: Input array.
    Output parameters:
        return array.
    """
    #- Length of array.
    array_length = len(array)
    i = array_length - 1

    #- Iterate Array from higher index to Lower index.
    while i > -1:
        #- Check Current item value with remove value.
        if array[i] == value:
            #- Remove Value from the input list.
            array.pop(i)
            #- Append None value to input list.
            array.append(None)
        #- Decrement index value by 1
        i -= 1

    return array


remove_item = 'x'
input_array = ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'x', 4, 5, 'x']

output_array = removeSingleElement(remove_item, input_array)

print "Output:", output_array
```

**Output:**

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python remove_item.py 
Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None, None, None]
```

Comment: The whole point of the question was to do it without modifying the array - pheraphs I wasn't clear enough about it. Check out Eric's and Daniel's answers ;)